# keep dbms_application_info settings across windows

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

We used to use toad but switched to plsql devepoler ide.

In toad:

I run in window

```
exec dbms_application_info.SET_MODULE('','xxx'); 
exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('123');
exec dbms_application_info.SET_ACTION ('yyy');
```

and continue to work in same window

```
select COUNT(*) from my_schema.VW_PROJECT_AUTH;
```

without declare begin end; block and not cursor but directy having output in output window.

What I am trying to with plsql developer:

set above dbms_application_info in command windows and continue to work with that session infos in sql window.

VW_PROJECT_AUTH is a view that requires module info.

I succeed in the middle of day somehow, but cannot do the again.

How can I use session infos set with dbms_application_info across command window and sql window?

**EDIT:**

After [Alex's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56655617/keep-dbms-application-info-settings-across-windows#comment99881499_56655617), I am at can now do:

```
select COUNT(*) from my_schema.VW_PROJECT_AUTH;
```

however results **0**.

However when I do run script in command window after these ones:

```
exec dbms_application_info.SET_MODULE('','xxx'); 
exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('123');
exec dbms_application_info.SET_ACTION ('yyy');
```

it gives me correct count something like **1000**.

Why could it be, the count is zero?

Comment: if it's a threaded application, there's multiple sessions being used and you're going to have look at putting that in a login.sql script - assuming they support that

Comment: Where is login.sql located? Thanks for info

Comment: ["For each connection that you define you can define an initialization script..."](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsconnectionlist.html) (I don't use PL/SQL Developer enough to know the best way to convert that into an answer; or if there's a way to share sessions as you can in SQL Developer...)

Comment: @AlexPoole Very close. See my edit please.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out:

Open sql window and do

```
declare
begin
    dbms_application_info.SET_MODULE('','xxx'); 
    dbms_application_info.set_client_info('123');
    dbms_application_info.SET_ACTION ('yyy');
end;
```

once you run above script, you are all set. comment above script and do your work in the **same** window:

```
select COUNT(*) from my_schema.VW_PROJECT_AUTH;
```